# In a regression with several ordinal dummy variables, how can I learn the impact of the dummy variable left out?

Tags: regression, economics, regression-analysis

Say we are regressing wages on education and race.  We have 3 possible values for race: black, white and hispanic.  So, I include the binary variables black and white in my regression.

After running my regression, I see that white has a positive coefficient and black has a negative one.  How do I know what sign the coeficcient for hispanic is? (in other words, how do I know how being hispanic affects wages?)

Comment: What other values do you know ?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the constant in your regression.

Not dealing with race, for item $i$ and a category with 3 levels W, B and H,

$x_{i1}=1$ if W, $x_{i1}=0$ if not W

$x_{i2}=1$ if B, $x_{i2}=0$ if not B

and model
$$
y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{i1}+\beta_2 x_{i2}+\epsilon_i
$$

$\beta_0$ is the coefficient for the baseline ( the final level, H)

Comment: What if I have 2 sets of dummy variables though?  
Eg: Race (black, white hispanic) and region (West, Midwest, Southeast, Northeast)

Comment: @DanielMangoubi The additional categorical variable would need to be coded similarly with dummy variables. This will change the model and the interpretation of the baseline to e.g. H and West.